# How to use libsensors in QT application?

Tags: c++, qt, linker, lm-sensors

I am trying to make a simple CPU temp program in QT for Linux, but I cannot get `libsensors` to work with my project. As soon as I include the sensors/sensors.h and try to call `int err = sensors_init(NULL);` the compiler throws an error `undefined reference to 'sensors_init'`. I believe this is a linking issue, but I cannot solve it.

Edit:

I can fix the problem if I manually compile outside of QT creator with `g++ -o main main.cpp -lsensors`.

Now my question is how do I pass the `-lsensors` parameter to the g++ compiler in the QT creator. I am using qmake.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add `QMAKE_LIBDIR_FLAGS += -lsensors` to the `.pro` file.